# Does Debezium MySQL Source Connector support mysql ldap pluggable authentication

Tags: mysql, debezium

Does Debezium MySQL Source Connector support mysql ldap pluggable authentication?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ldap-pluggable-authentication.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from Debezium User Group at gitter

Jiri Pechanec 07:14 @ranlupovich Hi, no, it is not supported as the library used to proces binlog is not supporting it